# How can i count by feedback number and insert in a cell?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Below is an example:

```
    A           B           C           D
1               product1    product2    product3
2   excellent   2           1           1
3   very good   1           2           0
4   good        1           0           1
5   is it poor  2           1           3
6     
7   product1    is it poor
8   product1    excellent
9   product1    good
10  product1    very good
11  product1    excellent
12  product1    is it poor
13  product2    is it poor
14  product2    excellent
15  product2    very good
16  product2    very good
17  product3    excellent
18  product3    is it poor
19  product3    is it poor
20  product3    is it poor
21  product3    good
```

I want to count how many feedbacks (excellent, very good, good, is it poor) a product has.
I tried to write a script but it doesn't work.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/path/file1.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for r in range(1, ws.max_row+1):
    if ws.cell(r, 1).value == "product1" and ws.cell(r, 2).value == "excellent":
       ws.cell(row=2, column=2).value = ws.max_row
       break
....
for r in range(1, ws.max_row+1):
    if ws.cell(r, 1).value == "product3" and ws.cell(r, 2).value == "is it poor":
       ws.cell(row=5, column=4).value = ws.max_row
       break

wb.save('/path/.file2.xlsx')
```

Comment: The structure doesn't make a great deal of sense. You probably want to use the `collections.Counter` class to count the feedback by product and type of feedback.

Comment: @CharlieClark I will try with `collections.Counter` . Thank you!